# Make custom validation for number in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a number filed, I need to make a custom validation for it like this

He can not write a number without put at the beginning of number one of these number

`077 | 075 | 078 |` the number must be like this `07701231231`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `starts_with` validation rule fits your needs here:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-starts-with

Since `077`, `075` and `078` are not valid `integer` values (would convert to `77`, `75`, and `78`), you'd use the following rule and handle that as a `string`:

```php
'number' => 'string|starts_with:077,078,075'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do so, one of them (accepted answer) is to use `starts_with` validation, another one is to use `regex` validation, here is the code for the `regex` validation:

```
'number' => 'string|regex:/^(077|075|078)\d+$/'
```